# SQL: remove records with invalid foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I just found a bug in my Rails app which would lead to certain records not getting deleted with their associated objects. The bug has been fixed, but I now have several thousand records in my database with foreign key values pointing to records that don't exist.

Is it possible to delete all records in a table where an integer foreign key references a record in another table that doesn't exist in SQL? How?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
delete from child_table where not exists 
   (select 1 from parent_table where parent_table.id=child_table.related_id)
```

the next step is of course to create a FOREIGN KEY constraint immediately (unless you're on MySQL MyISAM in which case you're out of luck on that).

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE FROM tblPerson
WHERE DepartmentID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM tblDepartment)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are several ways to delete all old rows. Let's say you have a table called `users` with an `id` column and a table called `posts` with a `user_id` column that should reference an existing user. You can delete all posts of non-existing users with this query:

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM users);
```

This has been posted by [Damir Sudarevic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1652459/5593430) before. It is easier and faster than the answer by [zzzeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1652447/5593430).

Once you deleted all offending rows, you can create foreign key. That will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Delete from ChildTable where ForeignKeyField not in (select PrimaryKeyField from ParentTable)

Answer (score 0):

yes - use a compound statement using 
"WHERE col not in (selecy id from FKTABLE) "

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a straight forward way. But you can write a script that handles that. Say your model is like this

```
class Post 
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Here,you can use a script like this

```
 Post.all.each do |post|
   post.delete if post.user.nil?
 end
```

Its easier and straigtforward then writing SQL. But this time take a DB dump before you try and do the magic

Comment: This was my original attempt, but we have too many records- it would have taken days to finish.